# Forcing the parent process to run first

Tags: c, linux-kernel, operating-system, fork

On my system(Opensuse) by default the child process always executes first, after fork. There are also ways to force the child process to run first. I would like to know if there is any way to force the parent process to run first?

Comment: It depends on the type of os and context switching time.
The only way you can do is to write sleep(time) in child so that it gets cpu after parent process

Comment: Yeah that would happen but even then, the Child has to run once to execute sleep/sigsuspend.

Comment: You can arrange for the child to be created in a `SIGSTOP`ed state via `ptrace`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this method

```
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == -1)
    abort();
else if (pid == 0) 
{
    raise(SIGSTOP); // stop the child
} 
else 
{
    waitpid(pid, NULL, WUNTRACED); // wait until the child is stopped
    kill(pid, SIGCONT); // resume the child
}
```